# not able to call backend running on localhost in react native

Tags: react-native, fetch, mobile-development

when i am making a fetch call to backend route running in my local i am getting back response in catch block.

> TypeError: Network request failed

```
let testLocal = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/test-817a8/us-central1/app/heartbeat'
fetch(testLocal, {
  method: 'GET',
}).then(res => {
  console.log("success")
  console.log("Form submitted:", res)
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("error occured:" + err)
})
```

Comment: i was faced this issue before, and it was about my android emulator. The android version of emulator was 4 i guess. And then i installed android 7 emulator, then error went away. In your case maybe you should replace 127.0.0.1 with localhost

Comment: Use your ipv4 and not loopback address.

Answer (score 0):

In this problem, you need to replace the IP address:
Instead of (127.0.0.1) localhost you need to use your IPv4 adressse (something like: 192.168.x.x)